# Error when trying to refer to a field by name

Tags: javascript

I am getting an error (`document.my_formm.fieldName.value is null or not an object`) from the below code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>(Type a title for your page here)</title>

    <script language=JavaScript>
    function check_length(my_formm,fieldName)
    {
      alert(fieldName);
      alert(document.my_formm.fieldName.value);
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name=my_form method=post>
      <input type="text" onChange=check_length("my_form","my_text"); name=my_text rows=4 cols=30 value="">
      <br>
      <input size=1 value=50 name=text_num> Characters Left
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What error? What have you tried so far?

Comment: `checkCompanyName()` is not defined ?

Comment: please specify what the issue is - 'the error' is not specific enough

Comment: Are you sure, you wanted to ask something here?

Comment: first alert is displaying the field name but the second one is showing "document.my_formm.fieldName.value is null or not an object"

Comment: That's because you need to use `my_form` and not `my_formm`. You have a typo.

Comment: I don't think it's a typo -- he's trying to use a variable to specify the form name and the field name (take a look at how he's calling the function).

Comment: Don't forget to pick an answer if you found one helpful. Click the green check mark.

Answer (score 6):

Your check_length function is using variables to identify the form and field names, however, by using dot notation, you are referring to a element of document **named** `my_formm`. When you are are using variable names, you should use the bracket notation instead:

```
function check_length(my_formm,fieldName)
{
  alert(fieldName); 
  alert(document[my_formm][fieldName].value); 
}
```

Also, you should really quote attributes in your input:

```
<input type="text" onKeyPress="checkCompanyName();" onChange="check_length('my_form', 'my_text');" name="my_text" rows="4" cols="30" value="">
```

Comment: The standard way (DOM0) to access forms and form elements is: `document.forms[my_formm].elements[fieldName]`

Answer (score 2):

In your javascript you have referred to the form as 'my_formm' i.e. you have an extra 'm' at the end which is not present in the HTML, this could be your problem.

Comment: thats y i passing the form name as parameter in the check_length() method

Comment: but you are not referencing to the variable passed into the function because you have placed 'document.' in front of my_formm, also, you pass the parameter in as a string not the form its self, you want to remove 'document.' and change your method call to onchange="check_length(this,"my_text")"

Comment: is it possible by passing form name instead of this?

Comment: Yes but there isn't any need as 'this' already refers to the form you need, if you must could give the form an id instead of a name then inside your function call 'document.getElementByID(my_formm)'

Answer (score 1):

Why does your JavaScript method take in that first parameter if it never uses it?

Answer (score 0):

Just do `onChange=check_length(this)`

and in your function

```
function check_length(element)
     {
       // element points to the element in question
       // element.form points to the form if you need it
       alert(element.value); 
     }
```

Comment: My requirement is need to pass the form name and field name not using this.. Using that i should do the validation

Comment: @raja, you can get those from the element... `element.form.name` and `element.name`.

Answer (score 0):

In general it would be nice to write WHAT error are you getting...

anyhow `checkCompanyName` is not defined in the code you wrote.

Also you're passing two strings as variable, they do not have properties...

A better way to do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkLength()
    {
    inp = document.getElementById("myInput");
    len = document.getElementById("len");
    len.value = inp.value.length;
    }
</script>

<input id="myInput" onkeyup="checkLength()" />
<input id="len" />
```

**EDIT AFTER COMMENT**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkLength(inputname, lenname)
    {
    inp = document.getElementById(inputname);
    len = document.getElementById(lenname);
    len.value = inp.value.length;
    }
</script>

<input id="myInput" onkeyup="checkLength('myInput', 'len')" />
<input id="len" />
```

Comment: Hi:
My requirement is need to pass the form name and field name.. Using that i should do the validation

Answer (score 0):

`document.my_formm` looks for a form named `my_formm`. You need to use the associative array sintax instead, like `document[my_formm]`, which will pass the value in `my_formm` at runtime, rather than looking for a property in the `document` object called `my_formm` (which doesn't exist).